# Redirecting an iOS MDM native agent

Tags: ios, http, redirect, mobile, mdm

I’ve observed a strange but consistent behavior of the iOS MDM native agent.

When we redirected it to another URL by responding with an HTTP 301, 302 or 307, the agent has changed its HTTP PUT verb to GET while dropping the HTTP request body completely.

For example, this was the device’s first HTTP request to [URL-1]:

```
PUT [URL-1] HTTP/1.1
Host: [HOST]
User-Agent: MDM/1.0
Content-Length: 306
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-apple-aspen-mdm
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
       <key>Status</key>
       <string>Idle</string>
       <key>UDID</key>
       <string>86ff0b7c0129f1c1ed4ff36984c1a2a3e5e06c81</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

We have responded with HTTP 301 and redirected it to [URL-2]:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: [URL-2]
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:48:31 GMT
Content-Length: 182
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="[URL-2]">here</a></body>
```

The device has accessed [URL-2] with this HTTP request (changed the HTTP verb to GET and dropped the 
HTTP body completely):

```
GET [URL-2] HTTP/1.1
Host: [HOST]
User-Agent: MDM/1.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

Does the MDM native agent support HTTP redirections?
If it does, what do we need to change in order for it to not drop the HTTP body and not change the HTTP PUT verb?

Answer (score 1):

It supports HTTP redirections with exceptions. Use a Secure Layer for redirection instead.